# Checkbox CSS Issue on iPad/iPhone /ios

Tags: css, ios, iphone, flexbox, css-selectors

My site is completely fine on all browsers, but when I check [this page](https://demo.kenakatarbari.com/services/tax-calculator/) on apple devices, the **CSS part of checkbox** is not working. I tried to fix this issue several times but I cannot find any results. Can you kindly help me to solve it?

screenshot of my page in apple device

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events in the Safari browser is running multiple times. Try the CSS below, it will hide the pointer events.

```
.checkbox {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: is it solve IOS problem ?currently i don't have any ios device its my client laptop screenshot that's why i ask you

Comment: It solves for the check boxes. Many browsers do not support various css properties. If thats what you want are finding then [visit here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-fix-css-issues-on-safari.html)